# проблема с сервером на Python

Tags: python-3.x, сервер

Парни, начал писать месседжер. Настрогал сервер

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
messages = [
    {'username': 'John', 'time': time.time(), 'text': 'Hello!'},
    {'username': 'Marry', 'time': time.time(), 'text': 'Hello, Jonh!'},
]
@app.route("/")
def hello_method():
    return "hello"

@app.route("/status")
def status_method():
    return {
        'status': True,
        'datetime': datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    }
@app.route("/send", methods=['POST'])
def send_method():
    """"
    JSON {"username": str, "text": str}
    username, text - непустые строки
    :return: {'ok': bool}
    """
    username = request.json['username']
    text = request.json['text']


    if not isinstance(username, str) or len(username) == 0:
        return {'ok': False}
    if not isinstance(text, str) or len(text) == 0:
        return {'ok': False}

    messages.append({'username': username, 'time': datetime.now, 'text': text})


    return {'ok': True}

@app.route("/messages")
def messages_method():
    """"
    JSON {}
    :return: {"messages": [
        {"username": str, 'time': str, "text": str},
        ...
    ]}
    """
    return {'messages': messages}

app.run()
```

И создал файл Sender.py, который берет текст и отправляет его на сервер

```
import requests

response = requests.post(
    'http://127.0.0.1:5000/send',
    json={'username':'Nick', 'text': 'Hello, Men'}
)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
print(response.json())
```

Но итог таков
[image: Но итог таков]

Хотя в Sender.py пишет, что все ок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот сама ошибка, когда перезагружаю страницу[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите, люди добрые(

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
'time': datetime.now
```

На:

```
'time': datetime.now()
```

И учитесь смотреть в текст ошибки – там же написано, что в серилизацию JSON попала функция или метод – найдите это место и добавьте вызов функции.